# Problem with laser diode

Tags: laser-diode

​I have a 1000mW engraving laser module. It was working well.

Unfortunately it suddenly lost its burning power and wasn't capable of engraving anymore, although the laser diode is still ON and generates the same focused purple-blue light and the body of the module gets warm when it is plugged in to power.

I changed the power source - the result was the same, it is just a laser pointer, not burner.
​
​Is the problem with the laser diode, or its driver? 
​

Comment: Are you sure that the focus hasn't shifted, even by a little bit?

Comment: Have you tried to measure the power it draws. It might give you some hint on what is going on. I've destroyed many laser modules myself, but this was due to poor circuit design...

Comment: Thanks for reply, No I'm not completely sure about the focus shift, It draws  less power than before, I think the diode is gone, the driver circuit is OK.

Comment: I'm guessing that since you can see the laser, you're using a 445nm. You most likely had a thermal runaway.